# Angular 8 - PDF generation using jsPdf

Tags: javascript, angular

Im using jsPdf to generate a PDF document which captures my html screen contents. I can see my downloaded PDF file in the download folder.

Can we change the path where the PDF is getting downloaded? Instead of having the default c:/downloads can we change the path?

Comment: Download path is specific to browser. You can change the default download directory in your browser.

Comment: Or you can select the option `Ask where to save each file before downloading` under `Advanced settings` of your browser.

Comment: We cannot write a code in Angular that would override the path to specific location?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is **NO**. It is not possible to change default download folder from Angular/Javascript or any other framework/language for that matter. It is forbidden due to user's security. That decision is always handled by the browser.

You could however define a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header that tells the browser if the file is supposed to be displayed inline or if it an attachment that can be downloaded and saved locally.